# Why Get-Date throws Index was outside the bounds of the array error?

Tags: powershell, date

I am working on a PowerShell script that searches the computer for a certain string and puts the results in a array. When it is done, it prints the results of the array into a log file. The issue I am having is naming the file. I would like to have the name say "AAV-*date*.log". Where *date* is the current date and time in this format: YmdHMS.

The way it gets the date is by using `Get-Date -UFormat $Y$m$d$H$M$S` and stores in a variable, and looks like `$Date = Get-Date -UFormat $Y$m$d$H$M$S` and then `$Date` is called for when the log file is created. The issue is, when it runs, it throws an error saying "Index was outside the bounds of the array". I have tried the Get-Date line by itself and still get the error. This is error message in its fullness:

```
Get-Date : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At C:\Users\*******\Documents\*******\*********\*****\scanner.ps1:4 char:9
+ $Date = Get-Date -UFormat $Y$m$d$H$M$S
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Date], IndexOutOfRangeExceptio 
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IndexOutOfRangeException,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetDateCommand
```

I have tried Google-ing it but with nothing related to Get-Date in PowerShell. Any ideas as of why it is throwing this error and what I am doing wrong along with how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Uformat` is looking for characters with preceding percent signs. Not dollars signs which denotes variable names in PowerShell

```
Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
```

You were sending it a blank string since those variables are not declared. You would get the same error if you ran this as well

```
Get-Date -UFormat ""
```

There is more detail at [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1)